# Does PayPal support authorization and capture method for rouble currency?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've an application in which customer can pay with PayPal payments pro and  PayPal standard depending upon their choice. I've created a PayPal sandbox account with country namely Russia. But when i do payment using above method its giving me merchant currency not supported in PayPal pro API. It works fine in PayPal standard but then i'm unable to capture the payment. Its giving me an error "You do not have permissions to make this API call". But if i change currency to US dollar then everything works fine.

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/3001761)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal Payments Pro is only available in the US, UK, and Canada.  You could use [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/#ec), though, and that should work for you just fine.

Comment: Do you have PayPal link where this description is written. I mean i had read on all sites that PayPal Payments Pro is only available in the US, UK, and Canada on many sites but not on PayPal's site. If you have link to that then please give me a link. Thanks.